# Tangent line to the curve that is parallel to given line

Tags: derivatives

Find the equations of the tangent lines to curve $y=x^3+2x+1$ which are parallel to the line that passes through the points $(1,2)$ and $(3, 30)$.

What I have so far is,

Slope of the given line: $m=\frac{\left(30-2\right)}{\left(3-1\right)}=14$

Derivative of given curve $y'=3x^2+2$

Then I set the derivate equal to the slope that I found: $3x^2+2=14$, which gives us $x=±2$

I found the y-coordinates by plugging in the values of x to the equation of the curve: if $x=2$ then $y=13$ and if $x=-2$ then $y=-11$, and so the tangency points are: $(2,13)$ and $(-2,-11)$.

Then plugging in this information to the equation of a line $(y−y_0)=m(x−x_0)$ we get two tangents: $y=14x-15$ and $y=14x+17$.

Drawing the lines and the curve on GeoGebra shows that the lines are tangents to the curve, but they also cut through the curve. I thought that tangents aren't supposed to cut the curve at any point? Did I go wrong somewhere or can tangents cut the given curve as well? Sorry, I'm still pretty much in learning phase.

Comment: The statement that a tangent cuts the curve nowhere else applies only to quadratic (i.e. conic) curves. Most certainly not the case (**thankfully!!!**) for cubic curves.

Comment: In general, within differential calculus, tangent lines can cut the function's graph more than once,  and some times even infinite times. The term "tangent" certainly seems to be taken from classic geometry, but it is **not** an exact equivalent.

Comment: A polynomial curve of degree $n$ cuts a line in at most $n$ points, so here it can cut the curve in up to three points, of which two are the same if the line is tangent to the curve.

Comment: I was hoping not to get into Bézout on this, but of course a polynomial of degree $n$ cuts a line in *exactly* $n$ points, properly counted. I frankly think that every high-school student should be apprised of this fact, even if in full generality the theorem will not be proved for them.

Comment: +1 for using GeoGebra

Comment: The theorem of Bézout is most certainly a global theorem, has no local application, @mvw .

Comment: My apologies, @mvw. I was expecting complaints about cases like $y=x^3$ and $x=0$.

Comment: When you move to higher-order curves, you have to refine the definition of “tangent” to only look at how the line and curve behave near a point. Precisely defining this rather vague idea lies at the heart of a rigorous foundation for differential calculus.